# How to save another column updated time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `Post` model that have a `read_status` boolean column. I want to add a `read_at` column that saves timestamp of when `read_status` is updated.

How can I hook the event `read_status` is updated?

Currently I'm updating `read_statsu` by user click with these codes:

#### read_statsu.js

```
$(function(){
    $('.edit_company').submitOnCheck();
});
```

#### posts.js

```
jQuery.fn.submitOnCheck = function () {
    this.find('input[type=submit]').remove();
    this.find('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
    $(this).parent('form').submit();
    });  
    return this;
};
```

#### posts_helper.rb

```
  def read_checkbox(post)
    if user_signed_in?
      form_for(post, remote: true) do |f|
        str = f.check_box :read
        str += f.submit
        str
      end
    end
  end
```

Maybe I had better create a another model for read status?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a sub model of your `Post` model. Lets call it `PostRecord`.

So your `Post` model will have a `has_many` relationship with `PostRecord`, and `PostRecord` will belong to `Post`

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_records
end

class PostRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :post
end
```

Your `PostRecord` model will have:

```
post_id as type integer 
read_at as type string
```

In your `Post` model you should define a method like this:

```
def updated_read_at
 self.post_record.create post_id: self.id, read_at: Time.now if read_status_changed?
end
```

[More information on the changed? method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html)

Answer (score 2):

First you need to create a migration to add the read_at column to your posts table.

```
 rails g migration AddReadAtToPosts read_at: timestamps
```

Then add the following to your Posts model

```
before_save :updated_read_at
private
def updated_read_at
  self.read_at = Time.zone.now if featured_changed?
end
```

Comment: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create a migration to add the `read_at` column to your `posts` table.

```
rails g migration AddReadAtToPosts read_at: timestamps
```

Then add the following to your Posts Controller

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.update_attribute(:read_at => Time.now)
```

If a user clicks on a post, that posts' 'read_at' attribute will be updated with the current time.

Comment: Thanks @DarkMouse! but sorry I noticed that I didn't write all information I should have. I'll add information in my question.